# A highly pathological discontinuous function. Trying to analyse its value at irrational points and continuity behaviour

Tags: limits, continuity

Consider the following pathological function $g : [-1,1) \to \{-1,1\}$ constructed in stages, where $x \in [-1,1)$. Each stage $n$ adds rationals of the form $\{\pm\frac{m}{n+1}\}$ as jump discontinuities
such that $|\frac{m}{n+1}| < 1$ for the denominator $k \in\{1,2,3,...,n+1\}$,  where $m \in \{1,2,3,..., k-1\}$.
\begin{align}
g_0 (x) & = \begin{cases}-1, x \in [-1,0)\\ 1, x \in [0,1)\end{cases}\\
g_1 (x) & = \begin{cases}-1, x \in [-1,-\frac{1}{2})\\1, x \in [-\frac{1}{2},0)\\-1, x \in [0,\frac{1}{2})\\1, x \in [\frac{1}{2},1)\end{cases}\\
g_2 (x) & = \begin{cases}-1, x \in [-1,-\frac{2}{3})\\1, x \in [-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2})\\-1, x \in [-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3})\\1, x \in [-\frac{1}{3},0)\\-1, x \in [0,\frac{1}{3})\\1, x \in [\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2})\\-1, x \in [\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3})\\1, x \in [\frac{2}{3},1)\end{cases}\\
\vdots
\end{align}

For clarity, the sequences of jump discontinuities at each stage is:
\begin{align}
\{0\}\\
\{-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2}\}\\
\{-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3},0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}\}\\
\{-\frac{3}{4},-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{3}, -\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}\}\\
\vdots
\end{align}
thus when $n \to \infty$ the set of jump discontinuities will be $\Bbb{Q}$

Below is an illustration of $g_0,g_1,g_2,g_3$

[image]

So in the limiting stage as $n \in \Bbb{N}$, we have $g(x)$ obtained that locally look like $\pm g_0(x)$ for every rational $x$, thus it is discontinuous at every rational.

However, it seems while the one-sided limits $\lim_{x\to a^{\pm}} g_n(x)$ is well defined for stage $n$, I have trouble determining whether one-sided limits of $g$ exists at all due to the oscillation, making it quite unlike the Dirichlet function

> 1. What tools should I use to analyse the class of discontinuities in $g$?
> 2. How to compute $g(r)$ where $r$ is irrational. While $g_n(r)$ is well defined for all $r \in \Bbb{I}$ by construction, it seems when $n \to \infty$, $g$ oscillate so much that $g(r)$ is not well defined?

Comment: Why the 1/3 instead of 1/4 in dividing the intervals? For example, you divide [0, 1/2) into [0, 1/3) and [1/3, 1/2).

Comment: I don't understand how exactly each $g_n(x)$ is formed. For example, $g_0$ is defined for all real $x$, the following only for $x$ between -1 and 1. Furthermore, I *assume* you want $g$ to be the limit of $g_n$, but you never say so.

Comment: @martycohen Each stage tries to add more and more rationals as jump discontinuities until all the rationals are obtained, and the stages are constructed in a way such that only those rationals are the jump discontinuities, thus each stage is like a square wave between -1, 1

Comment: @Ingix Edited the question to mention that $g$ is supposed to be the limiting step of the $g_n$

Comment: I would have thought $g_2$ went for a split at $\pm \frac14$, but it goes at $\pm\frac23$.
You should try to clarify what's going on.

Comment: Ingix: Also fixed that confusion of $g_0$

Comment: Does limit $g$ exist at irrationals? Seems like the sequence might oscillate between $\pm1$ endlessly.

Comment: By what method are you determining which intervals are mapped to $1$ and which to $-1$?  It is not the case that the first interval has fixed sign across the sequence of functions...  Without this prescription, why should anyone believe this sequence converges at any point?

Comment: So, I assume at step $n+1$ the sequence will go like

$$\frac1n, \frac1{n-1}, \dots, \frac13, \frac12, \frac23, \dots, \frac{n-2}{n-1}, \frac{n-1}n$$

as well as $0$ and their negatives of course. Is that correct?

Comment: Notice that this scheme skips $\frac25$, for instance, so your claim that it will go over all rational is not true.

Comment: Use the stern brocot tree to generate your interval rational endpoints.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri The nth stage generates rationals with denominators from 1,2,3,...,n+1 and then for each denominator k, m runs from 1,2,3,...,k-1. But yeah, I should have used the Stern brocot tree, that will be an easier construction

Comment: @jdods I am suspecting not, but what I am not very sure is whether the function values of g at irrationals are defined, since the construction will suggest they are well define at each finite stage, but the limit is oscillating, thus I am not sure what happens at the infinite stage

Comment: @EricTowers sign error fixed. It should make sense now and consistent with the plot. You are correct that the first interval always have the same sign